# Series capacitor buck converter small signal model

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, buck, small-signal

Does anyone know how to do the small signal model of the series capacitor buck converter?

I can't find a related paper talking about this one.

I think the small signal model is not the same as the traditional buck converter.

[image]

Comment: If it's a buck converter then it should be the same characteristics. The extra elements are only for size reduction (increase in frequency, etc).

Comment: [TI - Designing with our series capacitor buck converter](https://training.ti.com/designing-tis-series-capacitor-buck-converter).  Application note may help.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, 

I think the small signal mode is not the same. because capacitor will affect the circuit in the small signal.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat,

Thanks, I have seen it, but I don't get what I want.

Comment: Maybe this: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva750a/slva750a.pdf?ts=1664345205159&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.bing.com%252F